# How to remove 'suggestions' in Pycharm

Tags: python

I have a problem that really annoys me. I was wondering how can i remove/disable this suggestion or idk what is it. Here's the link: https://prnt.sc/pgekyp. Btw im using PyCharm.

Answer (score 0):

They are called "parameter hints". Most people like them.

You may configure the popup in the settings. See [Pycharm manual](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm-edu/viewing-method-parameter-information.html).

This is more like an IDE question like a programming problem.